# How to use variable in JSON object value while creating an object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create an array of object dynamically using for loop. The values for the key value pair of this object are fed from different arrays. So how can I create the array of object dynamically using for loop? I tried the following block of code but it was not working.

```
var anObj = [];
var charectors = ['Iron Man', 'Hulk', 'Thor']
var actors = ['Robert Downey, Jr', 'Mark Ruffalo', 'Chris Hemsworth']
for(let i=0; i<charectors.length; i++){
  anObj[i] = {
    charector : charectors[i],
    actor : actors[i]
  } 
}
```

The above code throws an error as I was expecting the array of object as

```
[
  {
    "charector":"Iron Man",
    "actor":"Robert Downey, Jr"
  },
  {
    "charector":"Hulk",
    "actor":"Mark Ruffalo"
  },
  {
    "charector":"Thor",
    "actor":"Chris Hemsworth"
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var anObj = [];
var charectors = ["Iron Man", "Hulk", "Thor"];
var actors = ["Robert Downey, Jr", "Mark Ruffalo", "Chris Hemsworth"];

const result = actors.map((actor, i) => ({ charector: charectors[i], actor: actors[i] }));
console.log(result)
```

with [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
var anObj = [];
var charectors = ["Iron Man", "Hulk", "Thor"];
var actors = ["Robert Downey, Jr", "Mark Ruffalo", "Chris Hemsworth"];

const result = [];

for (let [i, actor] of actors.entries()) {
  result.push({
    charector: charectors[i],
    actor: actors[i],
  });
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works as it is supposed to be thanks .. selecting as accepted answer

Comment: Glad I could help @LalasM

Answer (score 2):

Use `:` instead of `=` in your for loop.
Basic object properties assignement

```
 var anObj = [];
 var charectors = ['Iron Man', 'Hulk', 'Thor']
 var actors = ['Robert Downey, Jr', 'Mark Ruffalo', 'Chris Hemsworth']
 for(let i=0; i<charectors.length; i++){
   anObj[i] = {
     charector : charectors[i],
     actor : actors[i]
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. In fact that was a typo .. I'm editing it

Answer (score 0):

Push the values into the array using

```
anObj.push({
    charector: charectors[i],
    actor: actor[i]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. the assignment separator inside the braces is the colon, not the
   equal sign;
2. the name of the second source array is actors, not actor.

```
    var anObj = [];
    var charectors = ['Iron Man', 'Hulk', 'Thor']
    var actors = ['Robert Downey, Jr', 'Mark Ruffalo', 'Chris Hemsworth']
    for(let i=0; i<charectors.length; i++){
      anObj[i] = {
        charector : charectors[i],
        actor : actors[i]
      } 
    }
    
    console.log(anObj);
```